# Handling a large amount of large data files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, garbage-collection

I need to evaluate 1800 data files from a DEM simulation. Each data file is valid for a certain point in time and contains a list of particles and their temperatures. I'd like to plot the average temperature of a subset of particles over time.
Unfortunately I'm running out of memory after some time during the evaluation. Each data file has about 15 MB. Here's what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import linecache
import os as os
import gc

path = "E:/Simulationen/35_1100_700/DEM/post/dump/"

timesList = []      # create empty list for time
TcentralList = []   # create empty list for temperatures 

for files in os.walk(os.path.normpath(path)):
    for file in files[2]:           # files is a tuple with a list of filenames in the third element (index 2) of the tuple
    time = (int(file[0:6])-300000)*0.1+3       # read the timestamps from filenames (first six characters) and convert to time
            timesList.append(time)  # write time to times list for later creation of dataframe

            # Read the headerline (line 9), write items to column title list
            coltitles = [sub.replace('[0]','') for sub in linecache.getline(path+file,9).split()[2:]]
            
            columns=list(range(0,len(coltitles),1))     # list of columns to read
            
            df = pd.read_csv(path+file, sep=' ', skiprows=8, index_col=0, usecols=columns)
            df.columns = coltitles[1:]
            df.index.names = [coltitles[0]]
                      
            T_central = df[df.r.le(0.01) & df.z.ge(0.045) & df.z.lt(0.055)]['f_Temp'].mean(axis=0) # Filter all rows (particles) where radius r is lower/equal than 0.01 m and z is between 0.045 m (greater/equal) and 0.055 m (lower) and average their temperatures 

            # List of average temperatures of central particles for later creation of dataframe
            TcentralList.append(T_central)
```

I'm reading all files in the path. The time is obtained from the file name, converted and stored in a list - I'd later like to create a dataframe with a 'time' and a 'temperature' column. I'm then reading the data file to a dataframe and filtering only the particles in the central region, then averaging their temperatures.
The data files have 17 columns. First thing I tried was to read only the necessary columns by shortening the list 'columns', but this didn't reduce the memory usage.
Then I tried to manually start garbage collection (gc):

```
gc.collect()
del df
del T_central
```

This didn't help either. I also tried to re-initialize df and T_central to remove the references to them by

```
T_central=[]
df=pd.DataFrame()
```

but without any effect.

I'm out of ideas. Anybody got a hint for me?

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally found the solution: It wasn't pandas but `linecache.getline()` that occupied too much memory. Manually specifying the columns to read and the column titles of the data frame solved it.